# jQuery Selector for visible element with id like

Tags: jquery, selector

Getting elements with a partial attribute match in jQuery is pretty easy.  For instance

```
section[id^="sect_"]
```

would get all  elements with ids bearing the form sect_xxxx.  However, I need to to a step further and fetch - this is in a jQuery Mobile application - the section that is currently visible and bears an id with that form.  I have tried combining the :visible modifier in various ways but drawn a blank.  I'd be grateful to anyone who could suggest the right format.

Comment: `$('section[id^="sect_"]:visible')` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
$('section[id^="sect_"]').filter(':visible');
```

In fact, the `filter` method allow you to set a selector in a current DOM selection.
See [jQuery filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Comment: Thanks.  I have used filter often enough - didn't think of it this time though.

Answer (score 1):

try this

to check if the element is visible use  `is()`

```
 $('section[id^="sect_"]').is(':visible'){  //to check if it is visible..
      //your stuff if visible
  }
```

to get all element that is visible you can use `:visible` ..can use filter too..

```
$('section[id^="sect_"]:visible')
```

Comment: Thanks.  I have used filter often but was not aware of is

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to see if it's not hidden :

```
$('section[id^="sect_"]').not(':hidden').hide();
```

See on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/RWR7N/1/) for example.